# BootstrapVue Modal shows on page load

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to display a Modal component in my Vue app. I have tried several different methods of importing and using it but no matter what I do the Modal loads with the page. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

Modal.vue

```
    <template>
<div id="modal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>Welcome!</h2>
        <b-button class="close-modal" icon="x"></b-button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

    </div>

</div>
```

NavBar.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Modal></Modal>
        <b-navbar  type="dark" variant="dark" toggleable="lg" sticky>
        <b-navbar-brand href="#" ></b-navbar-brand>
            <b-navbar-nav>
                <b-nav-item :to="{ name:'Home' }">Home</b-nav-item>
                <b-nav-item :to="{ name:'About' }">About</b-nav-item>
            </b-navbar-nav>
            <b-navbar-nav>
                <b-button v-b.modal='Modal' right>
                    Modal
                </b-button>
            </b-navbar-nav>
    </b-navbar>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Modal from './Modal.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Modal
  }
}
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <NavBar></NavBar>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NavBar from './components/NavBar.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    NavBar
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav {
  padding: 30px;
}

#nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #545c63;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

#nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: #8aa096;
}
</style>
```

This is just the latest attempt, I have tried every solution in the official documentation, but nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MichalLevý That was a holdover from something else. I have removed it and will edit my code sample accordingly.

Comment: Why aren't you using `<b-modal>` instead of trying to build your own modal component?

Comment: @Hiws Changed that. I thought I had posted an answer about that.